# Changing the resolution of the iPod Touch 4th generation

Tags: ipod-touch

My son was playing with my iPod Touch 4th generation and changed the screen resolution.  I don't know how to fix this.

How do I change the screen resolution back to what it is supposed to be?

Everything on my iPod is way too big and I can't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have turned on the Zoom or Large Text feature. Head over to **Settings > General > Accessibility**. turn zoom off in there, or Large Text.

[image: Accessibility Options]

Comment: @Teresa Great! Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

In case your son does it again: If you ever get stuck at a fully zoomed in view, double tap with three fingers to fully zoom in/out.